# module 'tensorflow._api.v2.lite' has no attribute 'TFliteConverter'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a tensorflow model to tensorflowlite model

```
converter =tf.lite.TFliteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_model_name + '.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

But I get the error "module 'tensorflow._api.v2.lite' has no attribute 'TFliteConverter' "
Is it because I use LSTM in my model?

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo on your code. `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)` instead of `converter =tf.lite.TFliteConverter.from_keras_model(model)`